# How can I factorize $\sqrt[n]a-\sqrt[n]b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to factorize $\sqrt[n]a-\sqrt[n]b$ but I faced difficulty in evaluating log⁡〖(a+b)〗

Comment: I don't think that there is a way, in general (except $\frac{a - b}{\sqrt[n]{a}^{n-1} + \sqrt[n]{a}^{n-2}\sqrt[n]{b} + \cdots + \sqrt[n]{b}^{n-1} }$, if that counts). And there definitely isn't anything decent you can do about $\log(a+b)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "factorize" for an expression such as that, which is not a polynomial?

Comment: A way could be $\sqrt[n]a-\sqrt[n]b=(\sqrt[2n]a+\sqrt[2n]b)(\sqrt[2n]a-\sqrt[2n]b)$ but for what?

Comment: what if $a$ or $b$ is less than $0$?

Comment: Factorization is not without a rule. Usually, the rule is that the factors need to linear. Other wise $(x-y)$ can be factored infinitely! For simplifications we may factor it a few times. Otherwise asking for factors of $(x-y)$ is not OK..